# how to show next Card Item using CardLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, cardlayout

I have created a class which has a panel named cards and its layout is CardLAyout.
I have added card items.
In this class I want to create a separate method by calling which, layout switches to next card.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Container;


public class cards 
{
      public Container cards;

//creating objects for other classes
public cricGUI gu;
public cricMainMenu mm;

public void cardsList()
{
    cards = new Container();
    cards.setLayout(new CardLayout());

    //adding panels and contentPanes from other classes.
    mm = new cricMainMenu();
    gu = new cricGUI();

    cards.add(mm.contentPane);
    cards.add(gu.pane);
}
public void getNextCard(Container x)
{

}
```

}

So as u can see I have panels on other classes that I have added to my cards.
what i want to do is create getNextCard() method which takes the currently active panel as its arguements.
when i call this function it should switch the currently active panel with the next one in my CardLayout list.
How can i do this?
Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11652924/1057230)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have a look at [How to use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Basic principle is, that every card gets its own identifier (usually a String Constant). To switch to a specific card, you call

```
layout.show( container, identifier );
```

To implement a method like `getNextCard()` (better name would probably be `switchToNextCard( container, identifier )`) you could for example use an easy switch case construct like:

```
public void switchToNextCard( Panel container, String currentCard )
{
      switch ( currentCard )
      {
        case CARD1:
          layout.show( container, CARD2 );
          break;
        case CARD2:
          layout.show( container, CARD1 );
          break;
        default :
          throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported CardIdentifier.")
          break;
      }
}
```

In this Method CARD1 and CARD2 are your identifiers (String Constants) for your panels within your cardlayout. In this case it would switch back and forward between those two cards.